# codeigniter order by isn't working with zero values

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I've tried

```
 $this->db->order_by('order_status','asc')
          ->order_by('order_id','asc')
          ->get_where('order', array(
                'customer_id' => $this->session->userdata('user_id')
               )
            )
          ->result_array();
```

I also tried

```
 ->order_by('order_status asc,order_id asc')->get_where...
```

but if an order_status has a 0 value, it always is last. (ie, orders come out with a status of 1,2,0 ) My order_status field is a TinyInt. What am I missing? 
Edit: Table results look like this:

```
 | ID | Status |
   25     1
   26     1
   13     2
   16     2
    5     0
   27     0
```

What I need is:

```
 | ID | Status |
    5     0
   27     0
   25     1
   26     1
   13     2
   16     2
```

Comment: it would help if you included your table results so that we can have a better visual.

Comment: I just thought I'd show something interesting and so isn't offering an edit option that I can see. When I run the query (retrieved from the profile) in phpmyadmin, it works.SELECT *
FROM (`order`)
WHERE `customer_id` =  '7'
ORDER BY `order_status` asc, `order_id` desc

Comment: I just ran your code above in my local testing application running CI3 running the same information you placed in your database and it runs good with zeros on top.. I dont understand why you are experiencing this error. Theres gotta be somthing else youre doing or a parameter somewhere that youre not including.

Comment: Thanks for running this @CodeGodie. I'm coming in after another coder so he must have something somewhere I haven't seen. I'm not even sure where you would control something like this. But I'll start looking.

Answer (score 1):

You're ordering results FIRST by order_status and then by order_id.
The solution is:

```
->order_by('order_id asc, order_status asc')->get_where...
```

this way, you'll first order results by ID and then (if there are records with same order_id) order them by order_status

I don't know your code logic, but in this case i think it's the only solutions. Maybe you should reconsider your code logic

Comment: Fecchi I need it ordered by status first. I'm not clear as to why that appears incorrect to you and someone else (judging by the upvote).